# SQLite database backup android

Tags: android, sqlite, backup, android-backup-service

I have done the following to get SQLite database Backup/Restore working.

(1)get registration from Google.

[http://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup.html][1]

(2)Add the key to Manifest xml file

`<application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
               android:value="backup_service_key_from_google" />
    ...
    </application>`

(3)Add my backagent agent in the XML file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
     ...
    android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent" android:restoreAnyVersion="true"
    >
```

(4)Create a class called MyBackupAgent

```
    class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(){
      FileBackupHelper dbs = new FileBackupHelper(this, "../databases/"+SQLHelp.dbName);
      addHelper(SQLHelp.dbName, dbs);
   }
}
```

(5)Call the backup Manager for backup

```
BackupManager  mBackupManager = new BackupManager(this);
    mBackupManager.dataChanged();
```

After step 5, I do not see anything happening. I put a break point in MyBackupAgent. Nothing stops in the onCreate() function.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you simply have not waited long enough.  From the docs in reference to the call to dataChanged:

> This call notifies the backup manager that there is data ready to be
>   backed up to the cloud. At some point in the future, the backup
>   manager then calls your backup agent's onBackup() method.

The backup is not initiated right away. It is scheduled for a future time. You can initiate a backup right away by using adb on the command line.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html (Testing your backup agent)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do you incorporate the "adb" command in an application? I have a SQLLite database that needs to be backed and restored for application installation. It may be a bad idea to use the Backup service. I implemented a file backup using JSONObject object in the application folder that works now. Has anyone tried Google drive as a backup device? In that case, the backup file may be used by a different device. I have an application that uses Web service for data store and backup. In this application, I do not want to use a central server to do backup/restore.

Comment: adb is a desktop application and cannot be run from within an app

Comment: Is there a way to log on the Google cloud to see the backup file?